# DHCP based Server not updating A record

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp, xenapp

We have Citrix Servers which get IP from DHCP. After scheduled reboots, some Citrix servers are not pingable via hostname. nslookup is not able to resolve the hostname.

OS: Windows 2008 R2
Citrix Xenapp 6.5

Comment: Departing from the question slightly here but should your Citrix servers not have a static address? hiccups in DHCP and DNS could leave them uncontactable on a self assigned private range.

Comment: We have Provisioning Services in which our Citrix Environment in which servers boot from a Gold image stored on Citrix Provisioning Server.